# Tax/VAT when buying from USA in Argentina?

Tags: taxes, vat, shopping, online-shopping, ebay

I am going to Argentina for a month, and are therefore wondering if I can buy things (wooden puzzles) from the US and receive them in Argentina without having to pay tax/VAT?

Or is there perhaps a max price for which I don't have to pay tax/VAT and above this amount I have to?

Comment: What is the benefit of having things delivered to Argentina if you're only going to be there for a month? Shipping to there from the US can be incredibly slow and expensive (shipping costs + customs delays).

Comment: @BobbyScon The OP is apparently located in Denmark, shipping is going to be slow and expensive either way but I suspect she is hopping that dealing with the Argentine customs could be more favourable than the Danish customs. This also assumes the goods can be reimported to Denmark without incurring VAT (which might very well be the case, as there is a €430 allowance when travelling by air, which doesn't apply to goods delivered by post).

Comment: @BobbyScon The shops gives free shipping when above $100, and I would like to buy for ~$200. I would then bring them back in my baggage.

Comment: @Relaxed Yes, here in DK we can only buy for $12 outside of EU before customs wants a bg piece of the pie. So was hoping that there either were no import fees or the limit were higher in Argentina.

Comment: @JasmineLognnes Makes sense, I upvoted the question.

Comment: Have now spoken with some natives, and they do not recommend buying items from outside. From their description customs sound like they make the rules on the fly.